# Using Angular2 with Webpack does not show webpack folder in debugger

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I am encountering a couple of problems when using Angular2 with Webpack and any help would be appreciated. 
When I start webpack-dev-server the site works OK. However, I cannot see the webpack folder in the debugger (I use Chrome).
I suspect this has something to do with my project directory structure and where webpack is looking for files.

[image]

Here is my webpack.config

module.exports = {

```
entry:  './app/main.ts',

output: {
  path: "./built",
  filename: 'bundle.js',
},

devtool: 'source-map',

 resolve: {
   extensions: ['',  '.ts', '.js']
 },

plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ })
],

module : {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.ts$/, 
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loaders: 'ts-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loaders: 'style!css'
        },
        { 
            test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
        },
        {
            test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: "file-loader"
        }
    ]
},
```

};

Here is my project directory structure:

[image]

When I build the bundle (webpack or webpack-dev-server) I get some warnings at the end. So far I have ignored these but I believe that this is a different issue all together. I have included this for completness.

[image]